# Open chrome in c# with --userdata dir parameter and with incognito mode

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, google-chrome

When using same credentials to log into a server with multiple sessions chrome doesnt open and up on research found that opening chrome with following will parameters will work. when I create a chrome shortcut with the following it works. How do i use it in C# to open chrome.

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome%SessionName%.

Following is the code i have and it doesnt seem to work

```
  ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe", path + appname + " --user-data-dir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\%SessionName%");
  psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
  Process.Start(psi);
```

Still looking for a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`filename` is absolute path of executable. Correct usage of constructor like this.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", " --user-data-dir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\%SessionName%");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, tried this but it still doesnt allow me to open Google chrome in multiple sessions with same login. that tells me the chrome is still using default data dir instead of the one we are forcing to use.